# Adding text between two arrows

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and CSS which create two divs and two arrows as follow.

```css
        .arrow{
         stroke:black;
         stroke-width:3; 
         marker-end:url(#arrow)
       }
       .arrowYellow{
        stroke: #FFFF00;
       }
      .arrowGreen{
      stroke: #21e324;
       }
    .taskList{
      border: 3px solid black;
      margin: auto;
      width: 200px;
      font-size: 25px;
    }
    .container{
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap:wrap;
    }
    .task{
      flex: 1 1 0;
      border: 3px solid #808080;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 20px;
      min-height: 52px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .container .task1 + .task2 {
      margin-left: 300px;
    }
    .task3{
      border-left: none;
      border-right: none;
    }
    li{ 
      list-style-type: none;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
     <div class="task task1 text-center">Task Name1</div>
     <svg height="100%" width="30%">
     <defs>
     <marker id="arrow" markerWidth="13" markerHeight="13" refx="2" refy="6" 
    orient="auto">
        <path d="M2,1 L2,10 L10,6 L2,2" style="fill:black;" />
    </marker>
    </defs>

    <line x1="0%" y1="50%" x2="20%" y2="50%" class="arrow arrowGreen" />
  
    <defs>
     <marker id="arrow" markerWidth="13" markerHeight="13" refx="2" refy="6" 
    orient="auto">
      <path d="M2,1 L2,10 L10,6 L2,2" style="fill:black;" />
    </marker>
    </defs>

     <line x1="100%" y1="50%" x2="80%" y2="50%" class="arrow arrowGreen" />
    </svg>
    <div class="task task2 text-center">Task Name2</div>
    </div>
```

I would like to know how to add another div between two green arrows that point toward each other. Is this possible? Is there any other way around?

I would really appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Added a new div with class abc and added these styles

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.abc {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```css
.arrow {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 3;
  marker-end: url(#arrow)
}

.arrowYellow {
  stroke: #FFFF00;
}

.arrowGreen {
  stroke: #21e324;
}

.taskList {
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.task {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  border: 3px solid #808080;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  min-height: 52px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .task1+.task2 {
  margin-left: 300px;
}

.task3 {
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.abc {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="task task1 text-center">Task Name1</div>
  <svg height="100%" width="30%">
 <defs>
 <marker id="arrow" markerWidth="13" markerHeight="13" refx="2" refy="6" 
orient="auto">
<path d="M2,1 L2,10 L10,6 L2,2" style="fill:black;" />
</marker>
</defs>

<line x1="0%" y1="50%" x2="20%" y2="50%" class="arrow arrowGreen" />

<defs>
 <marker id="arrow" markerWidth="13" markerHeight="13" refx="2" refy="6" 
orient="auto">
  <path d="M2,1 L2,10 L10,6 L2,2" style="fill:black;" />
</marker>
</defs>

 <line x1="100%" y1="50%" x2="80%" y2="50%" class="arrow arrowGreen" />
</svg>
  <div class="task task2 text-center">Task Name2</div>
  <div class="abc">Task center</div>
</div>
```

Kept the svg absolutely, between 3 divs

```css
.arrow {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 3;
  marker-end: url(#arrow)
}

.arrowYellow {
  stroke: #FFFF00;
}

.arrowGreen {
  stroke: #21e324;
}

.taskList {
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.task {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  border: 3px solid #808080;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  min-height: 52px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .task1+.task2 {
  margin-left: 300px;
}

.task3 {
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="task task1 text-center">Task Name1</div>
  <div class="task task1 text-center">Task center</div>
  <svg height="100%" width="33%">
 <defs>
 <marker id="arrow" markerWidth="13" markerHeight="13" refx="2" refy="6" 
orient="auto">
<path d="M2,1 L2,10 L10,6 L2,2" style="fill:black;" />
</marker>
</defs>

<line x1="0%" y1="50%" x2="20%" y2="50%" class="arrow arrowGreen" />

<defs>
 <marker id="arrow" markerWidth="13" markerHeight="13" refx="2" refy="6" 
orient="auto">
  <path d="M2,1 L2,10 L10,6 L2,2" style="fill:black;" />
</marker>
</defs>

 <line x1="100%" y1="50%" x2="80%" y2="50%" class="arrow arrowGreen" />
</svg>
  <div class="task task2 text-center">Task Name2</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Which one do you want ?

Comment: Thank you, I want the first one but seems like it's not responsive

Comment: You want the text just in between the arrows?

Comment: I doubt if it can be made responsive :(

Answer (score 0):

Your original solution (and the variants provided here by others) all put the SVG directly under the "container" division, where your text divisions also live - making it tricky to align everything and control locations, scaling etc. While you can make this work with enough effort on tweaking margins/offsets/etc., it is best to try a different approach.

From what I see, the two 'arrow' drawings are separate and logically each belongs to its text box.

Therefore, you should consider structuring the HTML to reflect the logical makeup of what you are displaying, e.g.:

```
<div class="container">
   <!-- left-side division -->
   <div class="task task1">
       <div class="text-center">Task1</div>
       <div><svg>right-pointing-arrow-here</svg></div>
   </div>

   <!-- center division -->
   <div class="in-the-middle">
       <div class="text-center">midtext</div>
        <div><svg>(if-you-need-any-graphics-in-the-center)</svg></div>
   </div>

   <!-- right-side division -->
   <div class="task task2">
       <div><svg>left-pointing-arrow-here</svg></div>
       <div class="text-center">Task2</div>
   </div>
<div>
```

Note I have included only the content structure here, I will leave the styling to you (you will need to style all the inner s appropriately with `display:` and/or `float:` and `position:` properties to place them in the right order with respect to each other.